# Changing value of variable in list using indices from another list

Tags: python, list

I need to create a function that takes a sequence of integers, `indices`, with arbitrary length that will act as indices for a nested list, `the_list` and update the value at the final index with a new value, `new_val`. For example:

```
>>> the_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> indices = [2, 1]
>>> new_val = 'a'
>>> foo(the_list, indices, new_val)
[[1, 2], [3, 4],[5, 'a']]
```

This is equivalent to doing `the_list[indices[0]][indices[1]] = new_val` but I need to be able to this for a list of any length.

If list indeces has lenght 5 and the_list only 2 then the function uses only 2 first elements from indices.

Comment: How did you decide it's 11? What are the rules?

Comment: And what does `indeces` have to do with anything?

Comment: Is `a[indices[0]][indices[1]] = 11` not working?

Comment: How people are answering this question? It's extremely unclear.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Guessing intent

Comment: @IanAuld : I've edited the question, so maybe now you understand it?

Comment: @Trotom I've edited your question to be more clear but you still need to show what you have tried and describe what should happen if for example `indices` has a length of 5 but `the_list` only has two dimensions like the one in the example I added. Once you do that I will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your edit, you **Dont** know `indeces`. In this case:

```
def get_ind(a,ind):
    if len(ind)==1:
        return a[0]
    return get_ind(a[ind[0]],ind[1:])
```

Some examples:

```
>>>a = [[["a", 15], [12, 0]], [[12, 4]]]
>>>indeces = [0,1,0]
>>>get_ind(a,indeces)
12
>>>a = [12, 4]
>>>indeces = [2]
>>>get_ind(a,indeces)
12
```

You can also use python [exec](http://late.am/post/2012/04/30/the-exec-statement-and-a-python-mystery.html) in order to set/get the value:

```
>>>a = [[["a", 15], [12, 0]], [[12, 4]]]
>>>indeces = [0,1,0]
>>>newval = 217
>>>s = "a"+"".join(['['+str(x)+']'for x in indeces])+"="+str(newval )
>>>s
'a[0][1][0]=217'
>>>exec s
>>>a
[[["a", 15], [217, 0]], [[12, 4]]]
```

Comment: @Trotom if this is what you meant, feel free to accept

Comment: Sorry sir, but this is not what I meant. However I edited and showed better example so maybe now you can answer?

Comment: @Trotom I read your edit and changed it.

Comment: Is there any way to change value of the element instead of getting its value?

Comment: @Trotom Yes, I edited my answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You must give integer for index of a list so your only solution here is :

```
a[indices[0],indices[1]] = 11
```